# How do I migrate ONLY libraries from SharePoint Server 2010 to SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, sharepoint-on-prem, libraries

I do not want to do a whole migration as to avoid overwriting the current SharePoint Online configuration.

Is there a way to migrate only the libraries from the on-premise SharePoint Server to the new Online one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can using the 3rd party tool i.e. Sharegate or metalogix etc.

another workaround which depend upon the migration requirement, size of libraries and number of documents. You can try to manual migration, for which.

- Create document library on SharePoint online site.
- Open the SharePoint 2010 library in explorer ( open with windows explorer)
- then copy the documents from 2010 library window and paste inside the SharePoint Online window.

here is another example for manual migration if you want do some scripting:[HOW TO MIGRATE AN ON-PREMISE SHAREPOINT DOCUMENT LIBRARY TO SHAREPOINT ONLINE WITH POWERSHELL](http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/how-to-migrate-an-on-premise-sharepoint-document-library-to-sharepoint-online-with-powershell/)

Answer (score 2):

- Use Microsoft's migration tool: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool
- Use any of the third party migration tools. (do a web search for "SharePoint migration tools") Some of these are free for smaller amounts of data or for test transfers.

Comment: The MS migration tool does not support Server 2010: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool